# InputStream read buffer is split into two buffers

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream

I used the BluetoothChat example and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) for my application. I sent a command to a Bluetooth SPP device (Bluetooth to UART) and got back the answer. This answer has a variable size, but it is smaller than 255 bytes.

The problem is that I got back the answer split into two buffers. First a few bytes (mostly just two) at the first read and after that the rest. I didn't lose data, but I need it complete to work with it. I tried it with `mmInStream.available();` (see code snippset) but this was too slow. I also tried it with a `sleep(10);` but it didn't work.
What can I do?
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
        int bytes;
        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {

                // That was a try, but it's to slow
                //bytesAv = mmInStream.available();
                //if (bytesAv>0){ 

                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); // TODO

                byte[] buffer2 = new byte[bytes];

                System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, buffer2, 0, bytes);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer2)
                        .sendToTarget();
                //}
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the nature of the Bluetooth SPP profile, it does not provide any frame boundaries. 
So your application should read all data and re-construct any frame using some addition headers that you should add to your data over SPP.

Comment: is there a way to use brodcastReceivers or anything else? Because the Android App is the Master, therefore I always know that I have to read after my request.